# Pandas Autocorrelation Plot Not Showing Value of 1 at Lag 0

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm plotting a time series in Pandas, and am not sure why the `autocorrelation_plot` in pandas is not returning a value of 1 at lag 0.

This what I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/births.csv', index_col='Date')
```

`df.head()` gives the following:

[image: Head of dataframe]

If I pull the autocorrelation of different lags, I can see that it is indeed 1 at value 0:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
acf(df)
```

Gives the following results:

[image]

However, if I pull an acf plot, the results are not coherent.  There's no value of 1 at lag 0, and generally the results don't match the results of the `acf` computation in `statsmodels`.

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

autocorrelation_plot(df[:10])
```

Gives the following results:

[image]

These don't really match up with the results I had before.